# Blog as a part of a Wordpress site?

Tags: blog

I'm not sure how to word my search terms for this problem.

I've created a site in WP.
So, let's assume the URL is `http://example.org`

The 'Contact' page would be `http://example.org/contact`, for example.

I want to also have a blog on this site.
The blog would reside at `http://example.org/blog`

I have created a page named 'Blog'.
I've gone to `Settings > Reading` and selected 'Blog' for the 'Posts page' select list.
Now, when I visit the site, I don't see posts. How do I make my posts appear on `http://example.org/blog` given what I've done so far?

I'm not quite sure how to do that the right way.
Any recommendations would be appreciated!

Comment: Dumb check, do you _have_ posts to see? What _do_ you see at `/blog` page?

Comment: Sven: yep, Roots: http://www.rootstheme.com/


Rarst: haha yes :) The default 'Hello World' post.

Answer (score 0):

You say that blog will reside in `http://example.org/blog`. That's incorrect. It will be as a part of your installation `http://example.org`. Create two pages: Intro and Blog. In Settings -> Reading -> Front page displays - select - A static page -> Front page - and choose Intro, then in Blog page - choose Blog. Set your parmalinks to Post name. That's it. Add a post and go to `http://example.org/blog/`. You will have your post listed there.

Comment: Make sure that your page Blog has a slug blog otherwise the last request will look into subdirectory /blog of your installation and will fail.

Comment: Hey Frank, thanks for responding. Not sure if you read my entire post but I've already tried that and it didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the best way but this is how I resolved the problem.

I created a custom template and called it 'Blog' (name is irrelevant except for use in referencing it in this post).

I then selected the 'Blog' template for the Blog page.

I customized the Blog template to display blog posts.

If anyone knows of a better way to do this, I'm all ears but I'll mark this as the solution until then.